# How to change the inputted text's style inside an input element using Styled Components - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm stuck on trying to find a way on how to change the styling of the inputted text the user types into an input box. I've managed to change the placeholder successfully:

Styled component:

```
const InputFieldWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-left: 50px;
`;

const InputFieldContainer = styled.input`
  background: #252c37;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  &::placeholder {
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

React InputField component:

```
const InputField = ({ value, label, name, placeholder, type, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    {/* {label && <label htmlFor="input-field">{label}</label>} */}
    <InputFieldContainer
      type={type}
      value={value}
      name={name}
      className="form-control"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Full container using the `InputField` component above:

```
function SplashForm() {
  return (
      <InputFieldWrapper>
        <TextBox
          type="text"
          value={null}
          placeholder="username"
          label="username"
          name="username"
          onChange={null}
        ></TextBox>
      </InputFieldWrapper>
  );
}
```

[image]

But cannot do the same for the inputted text, as the padding and other styling for the placeholder isn't the same:

[image]

Comment: Share your full code.

Comment: can you share your code by any online editor so we can try and give you solution.

Comment: @RashedRahat I thought I added all the relevant code for this question as All I'm asking is how to style the inputted text in an input box using CSS with styled components, but I have added more to the question.

Comment: @MayuriPapat If you suggest an online editor then I can put it in there for you, otherwise the full code is now in the question. All I'm asking is how to style the inputted text in an input box using CSS with styled components

Comment: okay you can add CSS try this style for InputFieldContainer                                                                                                                        
  style={{   background: '#252c37', borderRadius: '15px', border: '0px', width: '450px',
  height: '75px', 'font-size: 30px', color: 'white' }}

Comment: @MayuriPapat That works for the colour, but the reason why I am doing the `&::placeholder {
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
  }` is due to the fact I only want the padding to be on the label inside the input field, otherwise it will pad out everything increasing the size of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

change it not in the placeholder but in the input

```js
const InputFieldWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-left: 50px;
`;

const InputFieldContainer = styled.input`
  background: #252c37;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  &::placeholder {
    padding: 15px;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).